# trap "" HUP v.s Nohup ? How can I run a portion of shell script in nohub mode?

Tags: shell-scripting, nohup, command-line-interface

I want to run a shell script over the weekend, but I wanna make sure if the terminal loses
the connection, my script won't be terminated. I use nohup for the whole script invokation, but I also want to execute some portion of my shell script in a way that if someone closes my terminal, my script runs on the background still. Here is a simple example :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start the trap" 
trap " " HUP 
echo "Sleeping for 60 Seconds"
sleep 60 echo "I just woke up!"
```

Please suggest what I should do ? The trap " " HUP seems like not working when I close my
terminal tab.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using `screen` instead of the `nohup` approach?

Open a screen session and execute the script as normal. Detach from the session using `Ctrl-a Ctrl-d`.

When you return, you can reattach to the session using `screen -r` or possibly, `screen -ls` and selecting the right session to restore.

Also see: [How to reconnect to a disconnected ssh session](https://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session)

Comment: There are some scripts you do not want to fail half way through, but you don't want to have to start screen for each time.

Comment: You can use `screen` and `nohup` together. Screen to protect your session and nohup to execute the scripts.

Comment: And if you are writing a script to be used by other people who can't be trusted to remember to start screen first?  Some scripts once they start operating really should fully complete.  For example a script that resets and updates the rules in an iptables firewall.  Or a script that sets up a complex routing table.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want `trap "" HUP`. not `trap " " HUP`.

> trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
>
> ARG is a command to be read and executed when the shell receives the
>   signal(s) SIGNAL_SPEC.  If ARG is absent (and a single SIGNAL_SPEC
>   is supplied) or `-', each specified signal is reset to its original
>   value.  **If ARG is the null string each SIGNAL_SPEC is ignored by the
>   shell and by the commands it invokes.**

The `" "` is not a null string, but `""` is.

Comment: I don't see the value of `trap '' EXIT`, since `EXIT` isn't a real signal; it's just synthesized by bash at script end. So you're just telling bash to do nothing additional when the script ends. That doesn't sound useful.

Comment: @tylerl, you are right.