# Re-connect to shell and e2fsck

Tags: ssh, shell, e2fsck

My server disconnected my SSH session which had a e2fsck running and I would like to re-connect to the shell and see the e2fsck output.
I logged into my server via SSH and started a e2fsck on a 3TB harddisk. After 20mins the SSH session closed (Putty) but the e2fsck command is still running. How can I see the output of the running e2fsck? IS there a way to re-connect to the e2fsck output?
And secondly: how can I prevent Putty from closing the SSH session?

Comment: start using screen or similar? this makes your command immune to disconnections and can run as long as it needs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reconnect to a disconnected ssh session](https://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session), specifically [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1095878/435764).

Comment: thanks - i can use it in future. What can I do with my current situation. I need to connect to the running e2fck....

Comment: The reptyr solution did not work. It only creates a new shell without connecting to the old one.